# Verifying validity of Intel.hex file records

Tags: java, bitwise

I have a class called `FirmwareFile` which represents and [Intel HEX format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) file. The file is constructed with the name, build time and build date, at a later point file data is retrieved from the database (another class handles this) and is passed in with the `setData(byte[] data)` method.

After the data is set, the method `isValidData()` should be called. This iterates through the data and analyses the hex records using their checksum byte. How is my code looking here? What can I do to improve it?

I suspect lines like the second one here aren't necessary, because I'm already dealing with a byte:

```
byte checksum = (byte) (sumLSB + 1);
checksum = (byte) (checksum & 0xFF);
```

Here's the whole class, which works perfectly well, but how can I improve it? For example, should I validate the data as it's passed in instead of with a separate method call?

```
public class FirmwareFile {

    private String fileName;
    private String buildTime;
    private String buildDate;
    private byte[] data = null;
    private String[] stringData;
    /*
     * This file has been checked and verified as correct using the checksum
     * included with each record. The checksum is computed by summing the
     * decoded byte values, extracting the LSB of the sum, and calculating the
     * two's complement of the LSB.
     */
    private boolean validated = false;

    /*
     * The dataCorrupted variable is used to point towards corrupted records in
     * the FirmwareFile data row. This should correspond to the same record line
     * number in the original firmware.hex file. if the number is 0 and verified
     * == true then the file can be trusted. if dataCorrupted > 0, then there
     * are errors in the file located at the corresponding row number.
     */
    private int dataCorrupted = 0;

    final Charset charSet = Charset.forName(CommunicationState.CHARSET);
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FirmwareFile.class.getName());

    public FirmwareFile(String fileName, String buildTime, String buildDate) {

        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.buildTime = buildTime;
        this.buildDate = buildDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fileName
     */
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the buildTime
     */
    public String getBuildTime() {
        return buildTime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the buildDate
     */
    public String getBuildDate() {
        return buildDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the hasData
     */
    public boolean hasData() {

        if (data == null || data.length < 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a byte array of data as received from the database
     * @return byte[] data
     */
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {

        this.data = data;
        String tempData = new String(data);
        tempData = tempData.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "");
        this.stringData = tempData.split(IntelHexRecord.Type.RECORD_START_CODE);
        log.debug("data size: " + data.length + " bytes.");
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of file data as ASCII strings, excluding the preceding
     * ':' and the trailing "\r\n"
     * 
     * @return the stringData
     */
    public String[] getStringData() {
        return stringData;
    }

    /**
     * Returns false if stringData == null or the file contains corrupted data.
     * @return validated
     */
    public boolean isValidData(){
        System.out.println("Validating data, start: " + new Date());
        if(!validated && stringData != null && dataCorrupted == 0){

            for(int i = 1; i < stringData.length; i++){

                String record = stringData[i];

                int sum = 0;
                int recordLength = record.length();

                for(int j = 0; j < recordLength - 3; j += 2){
                    int hexNum = Integer.parseInt(record.substring(j, j + 2), 16);  
                    sum += hexNum;      
                }

                // Two's complement calculation
                byte sumLSB = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(sum).array()[3];                
                sumLSB = (byte) ~sumLSB;
                byte checksum = (byte) (sumLSB + 1);

                checksum = (byte) (checksum & 0xFF);
                int recordCheck = Integer.parseInt(record.substring(recordLength - 2, recordLength), 16);
                byte recordChecksum = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(recordCheck).array()[3];
                recordChecksum = (byte) (recordChecksum & 0xFF);

                if(checksum != recordChecksum){
                    dataCorrupted = i;
                    validated = false;
                    return validated;
                }

            }
            validated = true;
            log.debug("Validation complete, end: " + new Date());
            log.debug("This is a valid Firmware File");
            return validated;

        }else{

            return validated;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `hasData` can simply be `return data != null && data.length >= 1;` like @200_success wrote.
- The `replace` calls to remove newlines can be done in one step,
  i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163204/2769043.
- There are some spaces missing in `isValidData`.

Now to the meat of the class.

I'd go even so far as to factor out the two steps `validateData` and
`isValidData`.  So in `isValidData` you'd do the caching of `validated`
and in `validateData` you'd to the actual checking.  That way your
indentation is a bit lower.

I think the combination of both `validated` and `dataCorrupted` is not
so good; I'd say one flag for "file has been validated" and another for
"error in file" would be better, so in that sense `validated` would be
the first and `dataCorrupted != 0` the second.

So:

```
public boolean isValidData() {
    if (!validated)
        validated = validateData();

    return validated && dataCorrupted != 0;
}
```

And then have `validateData` like:

```
private boolean validateData() {
    if (string == null)
        return false;

    for (...) {
        ...
        if (checksum != recordChecksum) {
            dataCorrupted = i;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

For the actual calculation, allocating additional memory
(`ByteBuffer.allocate`) shouldn't be necessary; I'd have to look up how
to do that, maybe someone else will answer that part.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've been thinking about factoring out the `isValidData()` method into two separate methods, so I'll get right on that. As for the call to `ByteBuffer.allocate()`, I've found this answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936865/571875 , I may refactor again once I'm happy with the rest of the class to extract the byte manually

Comment: You are right, a simple cast of the `int` to a `byte` gives me the data I need, not need for `ByteBuffer` at all.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setData()`, you fail to reset the `validated` flag to `false` and the `dataCorrupted` pointer. On that topic, what is the point of `dataCorrupted`? It is private, but write-only.

I am concerned about `new String(data)`. Perhaps you meant to use `charset`.

These few lines are problematic:

> ```
>     System.out.println("Validating data, start: " + new Date());
>     if(!validated && stringData != null && dataCorrupted == 0){
>
>         for(int i = 1; i < stringData.length; i++){
> ```

Why print to `System.out`? You have a logger. Stuff like this is probably more appropriate for `System.err` anyway.

The condition should be inverted, so that you have an early return, to prevent the awkward `else` way down there.

The `for` loop is weird, as it starts with 1. If that is intentional, it needs a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've updated all print statements to use the logger; the `dataCorrupted` variable is now printed to the log if a corrupted record is found. I've specified the `Charset` in the `String` constructor. The for loop starts at 1 because in the `setData()` method the call to `tempData.split(IntelHexRecord.Type.RECORD_START_CODE)` results in an empty `String` at position 0. This is because the record start code is always the very first character in the file. I've added a comment to clarify that.  I'm looking into the awkward `else` statement now.